# Excel - If Cell X is TRUE or Cell Y is TRUE then return False (and vice versa)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As from the title I require the following.

So if either Cell `A1` OR Cell `B1` contain TRUE then Cell `C1` should return False.
And vice versa
So if Cell `A1` or Cell `B1` both contain FALSE then Cell `C1` should return TRUE.

Comment: Please refer to this article on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask use an if formula, a quick search will help you work out how to write this.

Comment: `=AND(A1=FALSE,B1=FALSE)` should do the trick assuming True/False are the only options for the cells

Comment: `=SUM(--A1:B1)=0`, if not, then can you let us know what the options actually could be visually?

Comment: `=NOT(OR(A1,B1))`

Answer (score 0):

In C1, you put the formula:

```
=AND(NOT(A1),NOT(B1))
```

Hereby the result:

[image]